# Exit gracefully if exe.config is missing

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a program which is deployed to many production sites, each has its own configuration file that should be copied from a configuration folder.

I release the program without `exe.config` in near the `.exe`.

I can add some default config file with `<isDefault>True</isDefault>` tag and check if its there, but not sure whether its the correct solution, as this won't catch cases where `app.config` is not present.

**How should I inform the user that he should copy the correct `exe.config` in case the file is not present ?**

Comment: Not sure what is your problem... Check if file with name you need is present in location you expect it to be (i.e. next to exe) and show whatever message you want exactly as you've described in post. Now what part is causing you problem?

Comment: I am looking for a built in way to check if settings are present, therefore the question, I will use `File.Exists` if I wouldn't find an elegant way.

Comment: Why not to check for a setting you are actually interested in and than say something "setting XXX is missing. Either not configured in .config file OR .config file is missing"?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to create some fatal error handling. There are several cases that can lead to an application to be shut down unexpectedly. All these special cases, exceptions should be handled an uniform way. This is up to you, you should log this someway. That is for sure.

In your case, if the missing config file is vital you could throw an exception and shutdown the application - considering this as a fatal error. (Based on the title, this is the case.)

Maybe you could also display a dialogue box for these critical messages.

It is up to you. If you would like to inform the user directly you should use some graphical method, not only the log file.

If your application should start without the config file hacing a default configuration is a good idea. If you would like a really flexible solution, you should put this in a config file as you mentioned. This could be a good way to go.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but unclear how it related to the question. Expected case of missing config file can't really be considered "fatal error" and definitely I don't see any mentioning of exception handling in the question.